# sql: regular expression for certain pattern separation

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In table "example" I have a column "col1" with following strings

```
    some example text here x2.0.3-a abc
    some other example text 1.5 abc
    another example text 0.1.4 mnp
    some other example text  abc
    another example text mnp
```

Now I need following things

1. Add the part before `.` to another column "col1"
2. Add the part `.` to another column "col2"

So the output should look like this

```
       col1                  col2
some example text here      x2.0.3-a
some other example text     1.5 
another example text        0.1.4 
some other example text 
another example text
```

Some of the properties of the string in col1 are

1. String in the col1 always end with either `abc` or `mnp`
2. Numbers like these `x2.0.3-a` or `0.1.4` are properties. These properties may not always exists in the col1 string. But if it exits then it always exists before the ending string `abc` or `mnp`.
3. there is always an space before properties and after the properties i.e another space between ending string abc/mnp and the properties.

So my question is how can I separate the properties and add them into col2?
One idea that comes into my head is that try to find something with `*.* abc/mnp` or `*.*.* abc/mnp` that is anything`.`anything`.` space `abc/mnp`  OR anything`.`anything`.`anything space `abc/mnp`. I am not sure if I explained it properly.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Databases differ in what they can do with regular expressions.

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: Can you elaborate information on data of col2? Could there be patterns other than you supplied like _x3.1-a_ or _version4.5_?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you'd like your column to be splitted into 3 columns. You should explain your 2nd column's scope and semantics better, so you can make sure to regular expression regularly matches with it.

I built a regex in parallel to the data you supplied, so it may not match for future incoming lines. Regex is here : https://regex101.com/r/seLgca/2/ What it does is, it captures three main groups:

```
(.+?)\s?([a-z]?\d(?:\.\d){1,2}(?:-[a-z])?)?\s(abc|mnp)
```

Let's break regex into parts:

1. (.+?)
2. \s?
3. ([a-z]?\d(?:.\d){1,2}(?:-[a-z])?)?
4. \s
5. (abc|mnp)

Starting in reverse order, fifth part is simply matches abc or mnp. Forth part expects a space. Third part matches your second column if it exists, note that this part is for what you supplied so you can modify this part to suit your data better. Second part expects a space if it exists, this is for the lines contain empty second columns. First part is for the rest.

In Oracle, we have search and substring functions with regex as far as I know. So, you'll need a programming language to capture those groups.

I wrote a Java method for the purpose:

```
static List<String> getGroups(String content, String regex){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    List<String> groupsMatched = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(matcher.find()){
        for(int i=0; i<matcher.groupCount(); i++)               
            groupsMatched.add(matcher.group(i));

        return groupsMatched; 
    }else
        return null;
}
```

So, if I call the method with the lines you supplied like this:

```
for(String content : listOfContent){            

        List<String> groupsMatched = getGroups(content, regex);

        if(groupsMatched != null)           
            System.out.println(groupsMatched.get(1) + "\t" + groupsMatched.get(2) + "\t" + groupsMatched.get(3) );

    }
```

Here is what I have:

```
some example text here   x2.0.3-a   abc
some other example text  1.5        abc
another example text     0.1.4      mnp
some other example text  null       abc
another example text     null       mnp
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Comment: "In Oracle, we have search and substring functions with regex as far as I know" -- did you mean to say "we **don't** have"?

Comment: Oracle has [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm#SQLRF06303)

Comment: When I said "we have search and substring functions with regex as far as I know", I meant we have REGEXP_LIKE(), REGEXP_INSTR(), REGEXP_REPLACE() and REGEXP_SUBSTR() functions. I did not use any negation. However, if one would like to get groups of a matched pattern, I do not know if there is a way in Oracle.